# how to manage relationships between models in django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to make a system where when a student selects some course then, only this selected course's price and duration should appear dynamically while adding price and duration for the student.In the add student form i want to generate dynamically price and duration for the selected course .How can i achieve that

**models.py**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    basic_price = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    advanced_price = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    basic_duration = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    advanced_duration = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Add Courses Details'


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
    # i want price and duration generated dynamically linked to that selected course while adding through form 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Add Student Details'
```

> forms.py

```
    class AddStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'


class AddCourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = '__all__'
```

> views.py

```
def addstudent(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddStudentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            student = form.save(commit=False)
            student.save()
            student.course.set() # i am getting error here also
            return redirect('/student/view/student/')
    else:
        form = AddStudentForm()
    return render(request,'student/add_student.html',{'form':form})

def addcourse(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddCourseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            course = form.save(commit=False)
            course.save()
            return redirect('/course/view/course/')
    else:
        form = AddCourseForm()
    return render(request, 'student/add_course.html', {'form': form})
```

> add_student.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
                   <form action="" method="post" >
                        {% csrf_token %}
                     {{ form.as_p }}
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-center w-100 mb-3" value="Add">
                    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## add_course.html is also the same

Answer (score 0):

What you need to add is [many-to-many field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) - student can be in multiple courses and a course can include have multiple students.

How it displayed and calculated is depend on your views.

**Update:**

Ok, I didn't really reviewed your models properly. The question about how you are going to display is pretty broad without your code, but general points:

- Do you really need to save duration and price as `CharField`? It's way easy to have them as plain `IntegerField` or `FloatField` since they basically numbers.
- You are having way too many `ForeignKey` for something simple like price and duration. Those fields should be either saved as plain `IntegerField`/`FloatField`, or generated dynamically from the list of linked courses.
- You can refer to all students courses with [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/), something like this:

```py
# Get student instance
student = Student.objects.get(pk=1)

# Get all courses for that student
courses = student.courses.all()

# Get sum of basic_price for all of that courses
sum_price = courses.aggregate(Sum('basic_price'))
```

Comment: ok thanks.can you  please give me some ideas for the view logic so that it displays like this

Comment: .Thanks for your update.I want to generate price and duration dynamically from the list of linked course

Comment: @Mark yeah, snippet I attached is how you can get price dynamically. Read more about M2M field, refactor your model, create view and html template and come back when you encounter exact problems. Here's [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Than you so much for your feedback. I am very new to django so sorry for my bad question.I have edited my question.can you please look at that